# How do I predict a test case based on previous runs of the test cases?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, regression

I've been working on a problem where I have data about a few sprints. If there are 5 sprints (such as in the example dataset I've attached), How do I predict what should be run in the 6th sprint. Similarly, Once I know the 6th sprint, how would I predict the test cases to be run for the 7th sprint.

The simple solution that I came up with was to look at the last test case run for an id and if it failed, it might fail again and that should be run again. If it passed in the last test case run, then it would probably pass again and it doesn't need to be run again for the next sprint.

I was wondering how I might tackle this problem from more of a data science point of view.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjz2g.png